# WebDriver - Unable to locate element, extracting web page input fields

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm trying to extract all input fields from a web page with their Title and element details and to put them in a HashMap for later use in a JUnit test like

**This is the example code from the test class:**

```
accountDetails.chooseField("Date of Birth");
accountDetails.changeValueTo(dateOfBirth);
```

**That's part of the page source.** I'm trying to get all of fields with tag name "input". Unfortunately while running the test I'm getting the following selenium error:

> **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   **{"method":"tag name","selector":"input"}**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr class="subtitle">
    <tr>
    <tr class="subtitle">
    <tr>
    <tr class="subtitle">
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="caption">Staff Member</td>
    <td>
    <input id="StaffMember" type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" value="" name="StaffMember">
    </td>
    <tbody>
```

**That's the extraction class:**

```
public class AccountDetails {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebElement accountDetailsTable;
    WebElement radioButton;

    HashMap<String, WebElement> fields = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();
    WebElement addCustomerButton;

    public AccountDetails(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("officePane")));
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("MainArea")));
        accountDetailsTable = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
        addCustomerButton = accountDetailsTable.findElements(By.className("btn_def")).get(0);

        List<WebElement> tr = accountDetailsTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        for (WebElement el : tr) {
            List<WebElement> td = el.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            if (td.size() > 0) {
                fields.put(td.get(1).getText(), td.get(0).findElement(By.tagName("input")));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, the webelements storage would cause staleelementexceptions..wouldn't you anyway need to find the element again..

Answer (score 1):

To catch all input, i usually do like that :

```
List<WebElement> inputList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```

After you use like this (stupid exemple :D ) :

```
void showInputValue (List<WebElement> c) {
    for (WebElement e : c){
        Systeme.println(e.getAttribute("value"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have two td's in last tr. `td.get(1).findElement(By.tagName("input"))` will give correct result.